# ORDER BY sorting characters before numbers

Tags: mysql

My problem is, that MySQL orders characters before numbers. To give a quick example, we have this strings in a database:

`3, a, 2, 1, b`

And ORDER BY statement would return this:

`a, b, 1, 2, 3`

But I want it to be:

`1, 2, 3, a, b`

My database is `utf8_unicode_ci`, but that doesn't help. It still produces the wrong result. (I can't just check if they are numbers and then sort them to the top because an item could also be named "2something" and has to be before "asomething"). Any ideas?

*Edit:* I found the problem. In the database (which stores users), I was ordering by `CONCAT(name, login)`, and the name was `NULL`. MySQL orders `NULL` always at the top, so the characters were top of the numbers (the name field of them was an empty string).

Comment: Stop mixing up the variables String/Boolean/Int/Uint/Number/etc.....

Comment: It are all strings, but they may contain numbers, too. (I save usernames in that table)

Comment: you sure mysql order characters before number??? i don't think so !! just tried it.

Comment: Those numbers 1, 2 and 3 are not strings. If it is, the order by asc will work.

Comment: I am sure, that's the problem. And that are strings.

Comment: @Bondye, as afpel said they are String. afpel can you please tell the datatype of this order by column?

Comment: if datatype is character still it shud work in the manner..wirt `order by asc`.

Comment: Whaha these ppl. My prove http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/940b7/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY` should work in the desired manner if the column type is `character` or `varchar`.

Comment: Then it would be `3, 2, 1, b, a`.

Comment: yeah.. just saw the requirement.. let me change it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a collation to your sort field

Try

```
SELECT yourfield
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY yourfield COLLATE latin1_general_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
SELECT id FROM example ORDER BY IF(id REGEXP '[0-9]+',id,CONCAT('0',id) )
```

This will add '0' before letters and order it by it. Will return the original column

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `cast` in `order by` clause and check the result?

```
order by cast( desired_field as char )
```